# SQL Always on availability with failover and mixed authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, clustering, failover

I have 2 boxes running SQL Server 2016, and set up using Always On Availability. I have a listener set up to choose which server to talk to in case of a failover, which seems to work fine, except for the fact that I'm using mixed authentication, and my connection string is using a SQL Server authentication user rather than a windows one.

For example, the connection string in my application is:

```
Database=MySQLServer;Server=AGListener;User Id=sqluser;Password=XXXXXXX;
```

when I'm working against the primary, this works fine. when I failover to the secondary, then I get an error that 'sqluser doesn't have any permissions to the database'. If i run the below script on the secondary server:

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'sqluser', 'sqluser'
```

then it works fine again, but when I failover back to the original primary, I get the error again. it looks like on every failover, I have to run the update user script for the connection string to work.

Is using SQL Server authentication for a connection string in an AG environment just not a good idea? Or is there a step I'm missing? I would like my failover to be automatic, rather than needing to remember to run a script every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either create the login on instances hosting the replicas specifying the same SID as on the instance hosting the primary:

> **To Resolve an Orphaned User**
>
> In the master database, use the CREATE LOGIN statement with the SID option to recreate a missing login,
>   providing the SID of the database user obtained in the previous
>   section:
>
> ```
> CREATE LOGIN <login_name>   
> WITH PASSWORD = '<use_a_strong_password_here>',  
> SID = <SID>;
> ```

From: [Troubleshoot Orphaned Users (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/troubleshoot-orphaned-users-sql-server)

Or use a [Contained Database User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable):

```
CREATE USER user_name WITH PASSWORD = 'strong_password';
```